# Can streaming services, movies, series, be used to infect my computer?

Tags: flash

I have been thinking about starting to Watch Movies and series online using streaming (legal). I was wondering if there are any vulnerabilitys in these services which can affect me as a user. I have noticed that most streaming services uses flash. Correct me, if I'm wrong, but my memory tells me that flash is very vulnerable and can be used to infect a computer. I would guess that the bigger the name of the provider of the streaming, the more secure it would be. But I'm actually interested in a provider who is not very common at this date. Therefor I want to know, before I start a subscription, if there is possibility that my computed can be infected when streaming for example a Movie online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is : yes your computer can be infected by visiting a streaming site.

However, the risk is not necessarily unacceptable and this is not especially related to streaming : browsing the web in general always creates a small risk, notably of [Drive-By Download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download)

I would recommend to avoid any provider that is still relying on Flash, as HTML5 is doing the job perfectly for streaming and does not require you to expose your machine to Flash vulnerabilities.

There are a few things you can do to decrease the risks, like making sure that your software (browser, any plugin etc) are up to date, or, if you are paranoid, watch the streams in a VM that you rollback for each session ;)
Make sure that you *do not* download any third-party plug-in to watch whatever you are looking for.